# Extra whitespaces in java

Tags: java, loops, whitespace, indentation

I want to format the output of my code so that there will be an extra whitespace with each loop.

Example:

```
names[4] = "bob", "mark", "james", "frank";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    System.out.println("Hello, my name is " + names[i]")
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
Hello, my name is bob
 Hello, my name is mark
  Hello, my name is james
   Hello, my name is frank
```

This is just a small sample of my whole code but I have to do this with large number of names so I can't just put whitespaces line by line. Is there a way to associate how many whitespaces to put in according to each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple, first make it a print statement (not println which makes a new line at the end), then concatenate a string that contains 1 space at the end like this:

```
System.out.print("Hello, my name is " + names[i] + " ");
```

**EDIT** so what you want to do it print your statement as is, then loop through again inside your current for loop and print spaces the number of times as the current loop number, for example:

```
names[4] = "bob", "mark", "james", "frank";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

  for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
  {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }

  System.out.println("Hello, my name is " + names[i]);
}
```

**EDIT** a smoother way to do it.

```
names[4] = "bob", "mark", "james", "frank";
String space = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  System.out.println(space + "Hello, my name is " + names[i]);
  space += " ";
}
```

Hope this was helpful. :D

Comment: Ah I see. So that is the way to do it. Thank you ^^

Comment: I modified my post, i added a cleaner way to do it, it is faster then the previous one if that is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more elegant way to do it:

```
names[4] = "bob", "mark", "james", "frank";
spaces = "                ";  // as many as necessary.

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     System.out.println(spaces.substring(0, i) + 
                        "Hello, my name is " + names[i]);
}
```

Comment: this is not so nice, since if he adds more names then spaces it wont work, and you will get runtime errors, (yes you can add more spaces, but that is very cheesy and not dynamic at all)